# webView ShouldStartLoadRequest method not working properly

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am loading a webview with some url using:

```
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc-ecatalogue.xyz-ar.com/"]]];
```

then i am checking if the home page is being loaded then i dont want the navigation bar for this i am using:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    // Here you can check the URL

    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString*str=@"http://abc-ecatalogue.xyz-ar.com";

    if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"http://havells-ecatalogue.adstuck-ar.com/"])
    {


          self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
          NSLog(@"hello");

        return NO;
    }

    else

    {
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Back)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

but when the control goes inside the loop the web view is not loaded and the log which i have printed is continously printed.

Comment: Can you put an NSLog inside else{}? Please add the log that you see afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You have `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;` in both the `if` & `else` part. You should change it to `YES` in the if section.
EDIT:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    // Here you can check the URL

    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString*str=@"http://abc-ecatalogue.xyz-ar.com";

    if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"http://havells-ecatalogue.adstuck-ar.com/"]) {

        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"hello");

    } else {

        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Back)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I just tried out your code and it works fine. The NSLog(@"hello"); was printed just once. Try to do a 'Clean' project and delete the app from the simulator and retry. Your code doesn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: when the control goes in the if condition it is not loading the web page.it is getting blank.

Comment: That is because you are returning NO at the end of your if block. You will need to change it to YES to continue loading the url in the webview or remove it since you are returning YES at the end of shouldStartLoadWithRequest. I've modified your code and added it as an EDIT to my answer. Take a look.